# Is Deterministic MySQL Data Read function allowed in Amazon Web Services?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I tried to create a deterministic, MySQL data read function in my database on a shared hosting in GoDaddy (Linux). But while creating the function I got the following error.

```
#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

I have contacted GoDaddy Tech Support and they mentioned that I need Super User privilege to do this and they won't be able to grant that to me on a shared hosting. So I am planning to move everything to Amazon Web Services.

Before I do, does anyone know if Amazon RDS will allow the creation of this MySQL function or is there any possibility I can run into the same problems there as well? I had run into the same problem creating DB Triggers on Godaddy as well and worked around using Stored Procedure.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I know for a fact that you can change the log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter in Amazon RDS.

RDS has a thing called parameter groups.  If you want to change a setting, you create a new parameter group, change the parameters you want (in this case, set log_bin_trust_function_creators to 1) and then launch an instance (or modify an already launched instance) and set the instance's parameter group to the one you just created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, we did this just now on our live system and the reboot time took around 3 minutes in total, with the DB fully inoperational for around 10 seconds.